# Difference between ISNULL and COALESCE in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I read the comparison between `ISNULL` and `COALESCE` on msdn.
[Microsoft's explain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

The part that

> "Validations for ISNULL and COALESCE are also different. For example,
>   a NULL value for ISNULL is converted to int whereas for COALESCE, you
>   must provide a data type."

confused me. Someone could give me an example to make it more clear?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is valid query and will return `INT`:

```
SELECT ISNULL(NULL, NULL);
```

It will fail:

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULL, NULL);
```

> At least one of the arguments to COALESCE must be an expression that
>   is not the NULL constant.

It is valid query and will return `INT`:

```
 SELECT COALESCE(CAST(NULL AS INT), NULL);
```

You can check metadata for resultsets:

**[DEMO](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/370594)**

```
SELECT 'ISNULL',name, system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set ('SELECT ISNULL(NULL, NULL)', NULL,0)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'COALESCE', name, system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set (N'SELECT COALESCE(CAST(NULL as FLOAT), NULL);', NULL,0)
```